# Extract branch name in MSBuild prebuild step

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, build-automation

My ultimate goal here is to extract the branch name (which is part of $SolutionDirectory) in an MSBuild pre-build event and then inject it into my app.config appSettings.

I've been doing lots of digging and haven't really found an approach to this problem.

I would like to be able to do something like this during pre-build:

```
<XmlPoke XmlInputPath="App.config" 
  Query="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='BuildBranch']/@value" 
  Value="$(Branch)" />
```

Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to thank everyone for your help.  While the answers didn't quite get me what I wanted, it pushed me in the right direction for my needs.  Here is the solution that I ended up going with:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <XmlPoke Condition=" '$(TeamBuildOutDir)' == '' " XmlInputPath="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName).dll.config" Query="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='BuildInfo']/@value" Value="$(SolutionDir)" />
  <XmlPoke Condition=" '$(TeamBuildOutDir)' != '' " XmlInputPath="$(TeamBuildOutDir)\$(SolutionName)\$(ProjectName)\$(TargetName).dll.config" Query="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='BuildInfo']/@value" Value="$(SolutionDir)" />
</Target>
```

It turns out we were actually doing some funky stuff on our build machines that was structuring the directories much differently than locally.  We were making use of the $(TeamBuildOutDir) build property to dump all our binaries to.  After obtaining that knowledge, I was able to create the above solution for our needs.  This ends up creating a fairly consistent string that I can append to my BuildInfo property and process later on.

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to not rely on the path you have on $SolutionDirectory, because there's no guarantee that the value will be there, you could checkout your code in any directory and break the rule.

I assume all this is for build automation right? Independently of the tools you are using for the automation there are some important things to remember about [MSBuild Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx%22MSBuild%20Properties%22):

- Properties can be defined in your MSBuild script
- Properties can be override from the command line (This can be restricted from the script).
- Any environment variable that follows the MSBuild naming convention for properties will be interpreted as a property.

With this in mind this is what you need to do:

1. Define a "Branch" property in your script with a default value (i.e. develop, master). Allow it to be overwritten from the command line/environment variable.

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <Branch Condition="'$(Branch)'==''">develop</Branch>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. Send the apropriate value from your build system (Continuous Integration Server), it can be as an evironment variable or a command line property. It doesn't matter which tool you are using, all of them supports this. (TFS, TeamCity, CruiseControl.Net, etc.) Some of them will have this predefined based on the source control settings, in other cases you will need to do it manually. You can review your existing build log to see if there's a property already set for the branch or to check if you are setting the property properly.
3. Use the value in your pre-build event as required.

For development purposes, in Visual Studio right click your project > Properties > Debug, in the "Command line arguments" field add: **/p:Branch=yourbranchname** when you run the build from VS it will use the value defined here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe MsBuild Extension Pack is for you? There is task MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile and Action UpdateAttribute (http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.11.0/html/4009fe8c-73c1-154f-ee8c-e9fda7f5fd96.htm) to change existing attribute value. You have to define file, xpath and value to do it. But i'm not sure that this exceptions work with new versions of .net framework.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to take a look into this.  If this works for me, this will get me 50% of the way there.  I still need a way to dynamically pull the branch name as I switch between branches.

Comment: I can't actually try this myself, but perhaps you can run batch file in prebuild event and pass output of that file as msbuild property and use it in task, i showed you before. Inside that bat file you can run git command: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD (this command will give you current branch) and echo it as output, then perhaps there is some way to handle that output and use it later.

Comment: No need for a batch file, you can just use Exec to run git (best to specify --git-dir and --work-tree instead of relying on current directory) and get the output

Comment: Not using git.  Using TFS.